# My Network Places XP to Win 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, shared-folders, network-location

I am changing from XP to Win 7, I would like to "Add a network location." How can I do that? 
It seems that they changed the procedure for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Map network drive` in the Windows Explorer.

See [Create a shortcut to (map) a network drive](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/create-a-shortcut-to-map-a-network-drive)

Comment: I don't think this is what he's looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The specific "Add a network location" feature you're looking for is accessible by doing the following:

1. Open Windows Explorer by going to Start -> Computer
2. Right-click in the right side of the window and click "Add a network location" (for this option to be available, you must be in the "Computer" directory)

Information on the [Difference between mapping a drive and adding a network place](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-networking/difference-between-mapping-a-drive-and-adding-a/5dacb4fe-902a-4c78-ac39-a1b51f71ff7b)

Answer (score 0):

The Windows XP functionality of My Network Places, being able to create a shortcut to a specific folder on a network resource, has been moved to the Computer folder.

Either click on Computer from the Start Menu or click on Computer in Windows Explorer.

Right-click anywhere in the blank area of the right-side pane, and choose **Add a Network Location**. On the 2nd screen, double-click on Choose a Custom Location to open the familiar dialog box from XP. Browse to your network folder and add it.

When your done, the new link will appear in the Computer folder under Network Locations. It will no longer appear in the Network folder where it used to be in XP.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Explorer:

[image]

~~~~~~~~~~~